# Собственный PHPMail в модальном окне на Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, popup, phpmailer

Здравствуйте.
Хотел бы сразу сказать, что популярные дополнения для WP с формами мне не подходят и поэтому ищу способ отправки собственных форм из модального окна.

Схема примерно следующая: На обычных страницах **WP(page.php)** подключён скрипт **Fancybox**, он и помогает с **Popups**. Они срабатывают по нажатию на кнопки с помощью jQuery. На самой странице есть код html-формы в скрытом виде, появляется только внутри модального окна. Дальше нужно эту форму отправлять на почту, но с этим пока сложно.

JS от формы:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function validatePhone(phone7) {
    var reg =  /[0-9,\s]/i;
    return reg.test(phone7);
}

$("#calculation_form").submit(function() { return false; });

var pageurl = window.location.href;
$("#url2").val(pageurl);

$("#calculation_submit").on("click", function(){
    var phoneval    = $("#phone7").val();
    var phonevalid = validatePhone(phoneval);

    if(phonevalid == false) {
        $("#phone7").addClass("error");
    }
    else if(phonevalid == true){
        $("#phone7").removeClass("error");
    }
    $('#calculation_form .custom_checkbox').each(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).val('Да');
        }
    });

    if(phonevalid == true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/script/phpmailer.php',
            data: $("#calculation_form").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == "true") {
                    $("#calculation_popup").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                        $(this).before("<div class='success_msg'>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!<br>С Вами свяжутся в ближайшее время.</div>");
                        setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 3000);
                    });
                    $('#calculation_form').each(function(){
                        this.reset();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Собственно вопрос: каким образом связать **action=""** от формы с обычной страницы WP с phpmailer для отправки письма?
Наверняка здесь есть подводные камни и нужно копаться в **functions.php** или учитывать особенность CMS.

На многих ресурсах([напр.](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/)) пишут, что похожее можно сделать с помощью **admin-post.php**, но я так понимаю нужно целиком форму вместе с html написать в PHP-файле и на странице WP, в модальном окне каким-то образом вызывать этот .php.
Так же, есть множество англоязычных статей по поводу контактной формы без плагинов([напр.](http://www.mattblancarte.com/how-to-create-a-wordpress-ajax-contact-form/)), но это всё же не то и мне не нужна одна конкретная страница. Это окно с формой должно использоваться на многих страницах.

Буду рад любой полезной информации. Мне не нужна полностью готовая практическая часть(хотя было бы не плохо), хотя бы теоретические действия, чтобы разобраться как это работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно в ваших рассуждениях есть доля правды. Можно сделать так как вы говорите

1. Вам можно создать страницу с алиасом (например "system-sendmail")
2. Создаете файл в вашей текущей теме page-system-sendmail.php
3. В патаметре url ajax запроса '/script/phpmailer.php' меняете на '/system-sendmail/' Вот собственно и всё

За вами остается:

1. В page-system-sendmail.php подключить phpmailer
2. Проверять входные параметры POST
3. Добавить проверку на ajax
4. Отправлять письмо

PS все можно сделать более нативным способом посредством движка WP. см хук wp_ajax_my_action (и по аналогии можете найти хуки, для иных условий).

Данный ответ передает моё личное видение решения задачи

Comment: С этого места поподробнее "стандартным ajax обработчиком WP (он часто зависает)"

Comment: @KAGGDesign 1. куда нагляднее видеть в админ панели какие есть ajax обработчики, чем искать и наблюдать их в func..php 2. ставить плагин что бы наблюдать свои обработчики избыточное занятие 3. при создании пустой страницы со своей логикой вы получаем почти тоже самое что и при формировании ajax через хук (wp_ajax_my_action). Но при такой логике вы большую часть логики оставляете в func..php что ни есть хорошо, тк все тоже самое можно хранить в .js файле

Comment: @KAGGDesign при большой захламленности бд, страницы отдаются быстрее чем ajax запрос.

Comment: Я вас спросил про зависания. С чего это вы взяли, что  стандартный  обработчик ajax часто зависает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign "при большой захламленности бд, страницы отдаются быстрее чем ajax запрос" на средних и малых объемах бд, разницы никакой, только лишь в том, где храниться логика. На больших проектах иногда случается зависания (краши xhr, где корень зла понятия не имею, не так глубоко копал WP). Поправил ответ (все таки не часто, а иногда)

Comment: В общем понятно, бездоказательный поток сознания. Ничего там не зависает, ни на каких базах.

Comment: @KAGGDesign у меня не стоит задача доказать WP Гуру, что, что то там не так работает. Пишу со стороны разработчика которому приходилось делать ajax запросы и мне метод с создаем для этого определенный правил в админ панели понравился больше (все перед глазами). Про "Ничего там не зависает, ни на каких базах" уж вам ли не знать что у WP с бд все очень плохо. Очень плохая организация хранения данных.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72698/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-lazyproger).

Comment: Большое спасибо за наводку @lazyproger . Поковырял разные варианты, остановился на просто вызове php-файла из ajaxurl без страницы алиаса. Не смог разобраться почему mail() отправляет письма, а wp_mail() отдаёт 500 и в чём разница. И хотел поинтересоваться, насколько такой способ отправки писем безопасен и что следует почитать в противном случае?

Comment: @Idon'tknowhowithappened если вы вызываете в ajax просто php файл, то там не подгружается ядро WP, соответственно и функции wp_mail у вас там тоже не будет

Comment: @Idon'tknowhowithappened насчет безопасности) ставь капчу, а то роботы любят сайты на WP